# How does Facebook photo zooming work when zooming high res image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

The Facebook iPhone app loads the low res images first and then it loads up the high res in the background and it gets better when the image loads. What is the process in doing something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use a `CATiledLayer` inside of a `UIScrollView`. Check out [Advanced Scroll View Techniques](https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.8270634034.08270634040.8367260893?i=2094838247) from WWDC 2011. Slides can be found [here](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/104_advanced_scroll_view_techniques.pdf).